# Emacs multi-term doesn't work with right prompt

Tags: emacs, zsh

I tried using Emacs's multi-term mode with zsh, but it does not work with a prompt that extends to the right of the cursor (as some oh-my-zsh theme's prompt's do). The extra text is sent to zsh as a command. What do I do?

Comment: Looks like you are running `ansi-term` in line-mode. Just look at modeline does it have something like `Term: line`?